# Git alias with two commands (stash pop + merge) executes only the first command. Why? How to execute also the merge?

Tags: git, git-stash, git-alias

I set up a git alias like this:

```
git config --global alias.popmerge '!git stash pop && git merge master'
```

Then I call it, like this:

```
git popmerge
```

The "**git stash pop**" is executed, but the "**git merge master**" is ignored.

If I run "**git merge master**" right after the "**git popmerge**"... it sumply runs as expected, performing the merge.

I have other aliases with long sequences of commands... and they run flawlessly. It seems *something at "**git stash pop**" makes the alias process to halt*... Is it possible to avoid this behavior? How?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure, you first want to make your working directory dirty using `stash pop` and then do a `merge`? Wouldn't it be safer to first do the `merge`, then `pop`? Also, I am not sure ignoring the exit status, accepted as an answer, is really desirable. Doesn't failure in `stash pop` mean, there were conflicts? Do you really want to increase the mess doing another conflict-prone `merge`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The sole `stash save / stash pop` purpose is ONLY to allow the `checkout master` command [in this sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112852/git-website-update-strategy-how-to-sync-dev-and-live-repositories/6121482#6121482) to be always successfull. I want the stash stack to be empty, and the `stash pop` to be always successfull. **The exit status of a successfull `stash pop` is not zero.** Don't ask me why. That's why I needed the `;` workaround. Consider the chances of conflict coming from a `pop` immediately after `save`: it is zero, in this context.

Comment: ok, didn't know the save was based exactly on the same commit. Then, the only conflicts to be expected are from merging master to dev - fine. Too bad git command exit status behaviour is not really documented...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you checked the exit code from stash pop?

`&&` implies that the subsequent *list* is only executed if the exitcode is 0 (success).

You can simply ignore the exitcode by using `;` instead of `&&`.

---

Verify the success by using stuff like:

```
true  && echo ok || echo fail   # echoes "ok"

false && echo ok || echo fail   # echoes "fail"
```

Comment: Great. As suggested, I changed `&&` to `;` and it worked. Thanks also for the explanation.

Comment: @J.Bruni `and` @LeifWickland: Thanks! i like the attention to detail :)