# Is there a way to have ignored files show up in git status?

Tags: git, gitignore

Is there a way to mark a file in Git such that a "git add ." won't stage it but have it still show up under git status?

I know this sounds crazy, but the reason is I have some local script files that I'd like to see in my git GUI (Tower) browse window, however I don't want them added to the repo when I "stage all".

If I untrack the files and set status showUntrackedFile = Normal (or all) they show up, but then they get added back in by "git add ." or "Stage All". If I put them in .gitignore they won't get added/staged but they won't show up in the browse window either (which at least in tower is effectively git status).

Is there a way to get ignored files to show up in git status?  I'm guessing no, but am hoping for a cleaver work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an [alias](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases) that calls `git status` and
`git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard` after status...
Kind of a hack, but it should work. 
I just tested this and it works

- Set the alias:

  `git config --global alias.st '!git status && echo "**IGNORED FILES**" && git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard'`
- Run `git st` instead of `git status`

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/show-ignored-files-in-git/2196755#2196755)
[How to call multiple commands in an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126804/git-alias-with-two-commands-stash-pop-merge-executes-only-the-first-command)

Comment: This works reliably `git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard` but I'm not sure if/how to integrate it in Tower, but it sets me down a path.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if the other answerers are reading the man, but:

```
git status --ignored
```

shows ignored files as well.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html

Comment: One issue that I found with that is if you do a `git status --ignore` and there are no changes, it doesn't list the ignored files.  I couldn't figure out how to always get the ignored files to display

Comment: @Andy - Yeah that part is weird, but.....`echo "a"> blah&&git status --ignored&&rm blah`

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so; that would actually break the intent of git ignore.

From http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

> A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that git
>   should ignore.

I know it's probably not the answer you're hoping for, but I think it's accurate.