# How to pull one git remote to another remote locally

Tags: git

This is my first time running a project using git, so I will describe my set up and what I am trying to do.
Hopefully someone will be able to tell me how to do what I am trying to achieve, or how to set up differently in a more standard way.

I have a dev website that I have created a repository on.
I cloned a bare version of that repository onto the server
and have cloned repositories of the bare onto our local machines.

So my process is, pull from bare repository (named remote origin) to ensure that everything is up to date.
Make changes on my local working copy.
Commit the changes then push to origin.

So we have a bare repository which tracks all of the changes that we make locally.

I then want to pull those changes from origin to the dev website (repository has been named as a remote on my machine as dev)

What I thought I would be able to do is pull from origin to dev from my local machine as they both have remote aliases, but either it is not possible or I have not found the correct syntax. What I am having to do is ssh into the dev repository and pull the changes there.

Being able to work with remotes in this way will allow me to pull to dev, ensure everything works on the server then set up the live domain as a remote and pull to there.

The reason I am doing it this way is in my research everyone keeps telling me that you should only ever push to a bare repository, so I have set up a bare for everyone to push to so we can pull down into different locations.

Does this set up make sense?
is there a way to achieve what i am trying to do easily?
Is there a more efficient or standard way of setting up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get everything but you basically have two remotes, `dev` and `origin`. What you want is take the code on `origin` and push it to `dev`, I suppose.

So you can create branch `originbranch` based on `origin`, from what you want (`desiredbranch`) : `git branch --track originbranch origin/desiredbranch`

Then the same from `dev` : `git branch --track devbranch dev/desiredbranch`

To make sure you are working on it : `git checkout devbranch`

Then merge it :  `git merge originbranch`

And finally push it to `dev` : `git push dev`

And I suppose that's what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you. This does what I need to do. I was getting hung up on the advice that you 'should only push to a bare repository'

Comment: I think this rule is here because if you make changes in the non-bare repo, the conflicts will be harder to solve. So the rule is more : always make changes in your repo using local copies.

Comment: I tried this and it worked, but now on a new set up I am having problems. I continually get the error around pushing to a nonbare repository telling me that that branch is currently checked out

Comment: To do exactly what i was looking for i have ended up doing it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6121482/1100048) with post script hooks which pull the data into the dev repository when things are pushed to origin